# DeepOmit typescript helper working with a single prop but not with more than one

Tags: typescript

I have the following situation to solve, an type helper that can Omit some props recursively and in dot annotation, as described below

```
type DeepOmit<T, K> = ...

type Input = {
  a: string;
  b: {
    c: string;
    d: string;
    e: string;
  };
};

type Omited = DeepOmit<Input, "b.c" | "b.d">;
// expect to output { a: string; b: { e: string }};
```

I tried some solutions and I manage to solve for a particular case, with only one prop

```
type UnDot<T extends string> = T extends `${infer A}.${infer B}`
  ? [A, ...UnDot<B>]
  : [T];

type Dot<T extends string[]> = T["length"] extends 0
  ? never
  : T["length"] extends 1
  ? `${T[0]}`
  : `${T[0]}.${Dot<Tail<T>>}`;

type undotted = UnDot<"a.b.c">; // => ["a", "b", "c"]
type tailed = Tail<undotted>; // => ["b", "c"]
type dotted = Dot<tailed>; => "b.c"

type Tail<T extends any[]> = ((...t: T) => void) extends (
  h: any,
  ...r: infer R
) => void
  ? R
  : never;

type DeepOmit<T, Path extends string> = T extends object
  ? UnDot<Path>["length"] extends 1
    ? Omit<T, Path>
    : {
        [K in keyof T]: K extends UnDot<Path>[0]
          ? DeepOmit<T[K], Dot<Tail<UnDot<Path>>>>
          : T[K];
      }
  : T;
```

It works well when I try for a single case

```
type Input = {
  a: string;
  b: {
    c: string;
    d: string;
    e: string;
  };
};

type Output = DeepOmit<Input, "b.c">;
/**
 * type Output = {
 *     a: string;
 *     b: Omit<{
 *         c: string;
 *         d: string;
 *     }, "c">;
 * }
 */
```

but not working with more than one prop

```
type Output = DeepOmit<Input, "b.c" | "b.d">;
/**
 * type Output = {
 *     a: string;
 *     b: Omit<{
 *         c: string;
 *         d: string;
 *         e: string;
 *     }, never>;
 * }
 */
```

I also accept suggestions for improvements in the solution

Comment: Such deeply nested recursive conditional types inevitably have unexpected or unpleasant edge cases.  Given your example code, perhaps [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mZQMoN) would meet your needs?   (Please test against use cases you care about). If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yep, it's just what I need

Comment: Okay I’ll write up an answer when I get the chance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, deeply nested [recursive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) like `DeepOmit<T, K>` inevitably have unexpected or unpleasant edge cases.  The solution that follows works for the use case in your example, but it's possible you will run into a seemingly minor problem that requires a complete refactoring to address.

Here is one approach:

```
type DeepOmit<T, K extends string> =
    T extends object ? { [P in keyof T as P extends K ? never : P]:
        DeepOmit<T[P], K extends `${Exclude<P, symbol>}.${infer R}` ? R : never>
    } : T
```

The base case is that if `T` is a primitive type then `DeepOmit<T, K>` should just be `T` (we're not concerned with supporting something like `DeepOmit<string, "length">`).

Otherwise, `T` is an object type, we [map its properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html); for each property `P` that coincides with the path `K`, we use [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to omit the property key entirely (i.e., `{[P in keyof T as P extends K ? never : P]: ...}` behaves like `Omit<{[P in keyof T]: ...}, K>`).  Then the property value `T[P]` is transformed via `DeepOmit`, using `` K extends `${Exclude<P, symbol>}.${infer R}` ? R : never `` as the new path.  That type parses the union `K` for any pieces that start with `P` and a dot, and returns what's after.  (So if `K` is `"a.b" | "a.c.d" | "e.f"` and `P` is `"a"`, then the new path is `"b" | "c.d"`).

Note that the above formulation is careful not to [distribute](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) the `DeepOmit<T, K>` operation over unions in `K`, since `DeepOmit<T, K1 | K2>` should not be equivalent to `DeepOmit<T, K1> | DeepOmit<T, K2>`.  The recursive operation `` DeepOmit<T[P], K extends `${Exclude<P, symbol>}.${infer R}` ? R : never> `` parses the `K` union into a new union before doing `DeepOmit`.  If we tried to write it like `` K extends `${Exclude<P, symbol>}.${infer R}` ? DeepOmit<T[P], R> : never `` instead, we would get undesirable behavior where unions in `K` produces unions in `DeepOmit`.

---

Okay, let's test it out:

```
type Input = {
    a: string;
    b: {
        c: string;
        d: string;
        e: string;
    };
};

type Omitted = DeepOmit<Input, "b.c" | "b.d">;
/* type Omitted = {
    a: string;
    b: {
        e: string;
    };
} */
```

That behaves as desired.

A sketch of how that works: `DeepOmit<Input, "b.c" | "b.d">` takes the recursive branch since `Input extends object`, and since none of the keys of `Input` are assignable to `"b.c" | "b.d"`, no key is omitted.  The `a` property is mapped to `DeepOmit<string, never>` because no member of `"b.c" | "b.d"` starts with `"a."`, and this becomes `string` anyway because primitive `T`s are unmodified.  The `b` property is mapped to `DeepOmit<Input["b"], "c" | "d">`.  And this property ends up becoming just `{e: string}` because both `"c"` and `"d"` are keys of `Input["b"]`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhFgPIFsCWwA8AVANFA0lBAB7AQB2AJgM5TXABOq5A5gHxQC8AsAFBQCoWIqQo0oAewBGAKwgBjYFAD8UAN5QA2gAUozKAGsIICQDMhUAIa1dJMlVqFV5CADcIDKAC4o2gLpefILBsPBIaJhYOn54hHZitAAGACRqAKLE8gA2AK6UEBjaeNQgyFISWWwAvgB0qcymHlAASlWJKi3eUC7uDGxBglVdWHyjvKCQUACS5GA5SpzqAwKWPvRMrADcy1BSPmo7wfJrjMws2-whApQnG+eHghC3ZxfBVRfvYxPQKOhklFxQghfpgZnNgHgAERSGrySFQAA+UGhNUokLYFwA9AAqKDfKAg-6Ag6XFbPLY7PZLUkhJ50U4UmmfXhDbGYoA)